how to call api endpoint in django view using requests python library
here is my view for login functionality

class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'login.html')    
    
    def post(self, request):
        print('in post')
        data = {
            'username': request.POST['username'], 
            'password': request.POST['password']
        }
        url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login/"
        response = requests.post(url, data=data)
        print(response, 'res????')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return redirect('dashboard')
        return render(request, 'login.html')


my problem is that i got Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /endpoint/
how can i configure csrf functionality to make successful call and get response from the api which is again developed in same application
thank you in advance !!

An API is normally exempt from CSRF tokens. But it will here not make much difference: Django's authentication relies on the session, you query the API with a different session (well in fact, no session at all).

Exactly how does the login.html looks like?

In the form you need to send the CSRF-token, so, the form looks like:
<form method="post" action="{% url … %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit">login in</button>
</form>
where you specify the url of the endpoint. But the post function will not work. Indeed, Django normally works session-oriented to log in a user, but the session of your requests.post(…) is a different session then the one with which you render templates and communicate with the browser. Most APIs don't even work with sessions, but with tokens that are send with each request for example.
